# Firing an event after .slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested accordion like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var parentDivs = $('#standard div'),
        childDivs1 = $('#standard h4').siblings('div');
        childDivs2 = $('#standard h5').siblings('div');

    $('#standard h3').click(function () {
        parentDivs.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown({easing:'easeOutQuad', duration:1000});
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp({easing:'easeOutQuad', duration:1000});
        }
    });

    $('#standard h4').click(function () {
        childDivs1.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown({easing:'easeOutQuad', duration:1000});
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp({easing:'easeOutQuad', duration:1000});
        }
    });

    $('#standard h5').click(function () {
        childDivs2.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown({easing:'easeOutQuad', duration:1000});
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp({easing:'easeOutQuad', duration:1000});
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

The content div's contain radio buttons:

```
<p class="radioBtn">
<label for="input-1-1">Yes </label> <input id="input-1-1" name="clause" data-completed-id="1" value="1" type="radio" checked/>
</p>
<p class="radioBtn">
<label for="input-1-2">No </label> <input id="input-1-2" name="clause" data-completed-id="1" value="0" type="radio" />
</p>
```

What I am trying to do is get them to fire on change using the following code:

```
$('input:radio[name=clause]').change(function() {
alert("Test!");
});
```

But nothing happens when I change the radio buttons.

Comment: Your radio code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/xz6f76pr/

Comment: Your radio button change alerts "Test!" its working fine !

Comment: have you change script in $(document).ready ??? If not, your event is not attached to jquery

Comment: I have included query:<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: I know it works without the nested accordion, I'm assuming it has something to do with it.

Comment: Your code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/9njewqqj/
Can you make post more detail of your javascript console under your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`$("input[name='clause']").on('change',function() {
   alert("Test!");
 });`

Comment: `change()` which is already proven to work is just a shortcut method for `on('change')` .. no real reason this will improve anything

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. Try to put it in a document event, like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input:radio[name=clause]').change(function() {
      alert("Test!");
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've worked it out. I forgot that I was using the jQuery plugin iCheck which has it's own set of callbacks.

Sorry for wasting everyones time.